# Why can't I download spark?

Tags: sparkpost, civicrm-spark

I entered all my information in the sign-up area and it comes up with the following: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: spark or sparkpost? different things

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the inconvenience. We had a small glitch recently and it should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!  Assuming you mean [CiviCRM Spark](https://civicrm.org/spark) not [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/) then I suggest going to https://chat.civicrm.org/ and posting in the 'spark' channel.